# Detect if a LineString / MultiLineString is inside a Polygon or if it intersects it using JTS library

Tags: java, kotlin, intersection, jts

**Description**

So basically what I would like to know is whether a `LineString` (or `MultiLineString`) is contained in a `MultiPolygon` or if it intersects it.

I'm not entirely sure that it might affect, but the real case scenario is that I have a `LineString` that represents a hiking track, and I need to know through which world areas (which would be my `MultiPolygon`s) is that track going through. Or in the case it is inside of one of my world areas, I need to know which area is containing that `LineString`.

**My problem**

My issue here is that **I'm getting false positives**. If I perform the same check with a `Point` (to see if it is contained in a `MultiPolygon`), instead of a `LineString`, it works perfectly fine.

**Steps to accomplish my goal:**

1. Process my `LineString` from EPSG 3857 format to EPSG 4326 format (using this formula [Converting coordinates from EPSG 3857 to 4326 DotSpatial](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37523872/converting-coordinates-from-epsg-3857-to-4326-dotspatial) ), since the `LineString` I received it was in the EPSG 3857 format.
2. Read my `Geometries` (using `Gson` and `JtsAdapter`, since they are in GeoJson format, concretely they are `MultiPolygon`s). **This point shouldn't be the problem, since I use it to detect if a Point is inside a Polygon somewhere else, and works totally OK.**
3. Check whether my `LineString` intersects or is contained by any of the `MultiPolygon`s and register all the IDs of this `MultiPolygon`s.

**My code:**

**1.Convert my LineString from EPSG 3857 to EPSG 4326:**

```
private fun reprojectFromEpsg3857ToEpsg4326(geometry: Geometry): Geometry
{
    val e = 2.7182818284
    val X = 20037508.34

    if (geometry is LineString) {
        for (i in 0 until geometry.numPoints) {
            val coordinate = geometry.getCoordinateN(i)
            geometry.getCoordinateN(i).x = (coordinate.x * 180) / X
            geometry.getCoordinateN(i).y = coordinate.y / (X / 180)
            geometry.getCoordinateN(i).y = ((Math.atan(Math.pow(e, ((PI / 180) * geometry.getCoordinateN(i).y)))) / (PI / 360)) - 90
        }
    } else if (geometry is MultiLineString) {
        try {
            for (i in 0 until geometry.numGeometries) {
                for (j in 0 until geometry.getGeometryN(i).coordinates.size) {
                    val coordinate = geometry.getGeometryN(i).coordinates[i]
                    geometry.getGeometryN(i).coordinates[i].x = (coordinate.x * 180) / X
                    geometry.getGeometryN(i).coordinates[i].y = coordinate.y / (X / 180)
                    geometry.getGeometryN(i).coordinates[i].y = ((Math.atan(Math.pow(e,((PI / 180) * geometry.getGeometryN(i).coordinates[i].y)))) / (PI / 360)) - 90
                }
            }
        } catch (e: ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException) {

        }
    }

    return geometry
}
```

**2.Read my `Geometries` using Gson and Jts adapter:**

```
private fun getGeometries(gson: Gson): HashMap<Long, Geometry>
{
    val geoJsonGeometries = HashMap<Long, Geometry>()
    val geometriesFolder = File("geometries-folder")

    geometriesFolder.listFiles(getFilenameFilter("geojson")).forEach {
        val reader = FileReader(it)
        var geometry = gson.fromJson(reader, Geometry::class.java)

        if (geometry.geometryType == "GeometryCollection") {
            geometry = geometry.getGeometryN(0)
        }

        val geometryId = java.lang.Long.parseLong(it.name.replace(".geojson", ""))
        geoJsonGeometries[geometryId] = geometry
    }

    return geoJsonGeometries
}
```

**3.Perform the check to see which `MultiPolygon`s are related (either by containment or by intersection) with my `LineString`:**

```
val geometryIds = ArrayList<Long>()
geometries.forEach { geometryId, mapBoundaries ->
    if (routeAsLineString.intersects(mapBoundaries) || mapBoundaries.contains(routeAsLineString)) {
        geometryIds.add(geometryId)
    }
}
```

Any help would be very thankful!

Answer (score 0):

Alright, I got very wrongly the `MultiLineString` conversion from EPSG 3857 format to EPSG 4326 format. Basically, I wasn't converting the `MultiLineString`, only the first coordinate was being converted. But there are many `Geometry` objectes inside a `MultiLineString` and each of them has many coordinates.

So steps 2 and 3 were correct.

The original conversion was:

```
for (i in 0 until geometry.numGeometries) {
    for (j in 0 until geometry.getGeometryN(i).coordinates.size) {
        val coordinate = geometry.getGeometryN(i).coordinates[i]
        geometry.getGeometryN(i).coordinates[i].x = (coordinate.x * 180) / X
        geometry.getGeometryN(i).coordinates[i].y = coordinate.y / (X / 180)
        geometry.getGeometryN(i).coordinates[i].y = ((Math.atan(Math.pow(e,((PI / 180) * geometry.getGeometryN(i).coordinates[i].y)))) / (PI / 360)) - 90
    }
}
```

But should have been:

```
for (i in 0 until geometry.numGeometries) {
    for (j in 0 until geometry.getGeometryN(i).coordinates.size) {
        val coordinate = geometry.getGeometryN(i).coordinates[j]
        geometry.getGeometryN(i).coordinates[j].x = (coordinate.x * 180) / X
        geometry.getGeometryN(i).coordinates[j].y = coordinate.y / (X / 180)
        geometry.getGeometryN(i).coordinates[j].y = ((Math.atan(Math.pow(e,((PI / 180) * geometry.getGeometryN(i).coordinates[j].y)))) / (PI / 360)) - 90
    }
}
```