# Swift - Coordinate Transformation from EPSG:4326 to 3857

Tags: swift, gps, gis, proj, epsg

I would like to know a Swift library or method that I can use to convert from 4326 to 3857. I have referred some libraries such as [Proj4Swift](https://github.com/fangpenlin/Proj4Swift) and [Proj.4](https://github.com/Ryandev/Proj4-iOS), but to no avail. The first link does not has a workable download and the second does not has a documentation. Would anyone suggest a library or method that I can use to achieve this in Swift?

I have also referred other similar questions but could not find a proper solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, since I couldn't find a clear and direct answer, I wrote the code in Swift, by referring the [following](https://www.masinamichele.it/2018/05/04/gis-the-math-to-convert-from-epsg3857-to-wgs-84/) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40403522/7196681). It's as follows.

```
func getCoordinatesInEPSG3857(longitudeInEPSG4326: Double, latitudeInEPSG4326: Double) -> (Double, Double) {
    let longitudeInEPSG3857 = (longitudeInEPSG4326 * 20037508.34 / 180)
    let latitudeInEPSG3857 = (log(tan((90 + latitudeInEPSG4326) * Double.pi / 360)) / (Double.pi / 180)) * (20037508.34 / 180)

    return (longitudeInEPSG3857, latitudeInEPSG3857)
}
```

Here, you can pass the coordinates which are in EPSG:4326 and the function returns the coordinates in EPSG:3857.